# Coloured-rarity firearm's damage stat's true in Riptide?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

In Dead Island (1), coloured-rarity firearms did not display their true damage stat. You could find a green-rarity (one rarity above lowest) firearm with a low damage stat displayed, that did more damage in one bullet than an orange-rarity (most rare) firearm with a higher damage stat displayed.

To find out the actual damage of a coloured-rarity firearm, you had to do some actual tests.

Is this still the case in Dead Island Riptide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing says that the damage listed in the stats of a coloured-rarity firearm is...TRUE in Dead Island Riptide.